# Asymptotic expansion of $1/(\mathrm{i}x+1)^\kappa$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\kappa>0$ and $\mathrm{i}^2=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

How to compute the asymptotic expansion of the function $1/(\mathrm{i}x+1)^\kappa$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\kappa>0$, and $\mathrm{i}^2=-1$?

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{{(ix + 1)^\kappa  }} = \frac{1}{{(ix)^\kappa  }}\frac{1}{{(1 + 1/(ix))^\kappa  }} = \frac{1}{{(ix)^\kappa  }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  \binom{\kappa}{n} \frac{1}{{(ix)^n }}
$$ for $x>1$.

Comment: @Gary It should have been $\frac1{(ix)^\kappa}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\kappa}n \frac1{(ix)^n}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Right, thanks.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio How do you get the last sum? Whats is the name of this series?

Comment: @TooManyQuestionsInLife Binomial series.

Comment: @Gary Now that I think about it: is it actually ok to take out the $(ix)^\kappa$ if $\kappa\notin\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio It is OK. You just need to specify the branch of $i^\kappa$. If you think about it, $\arg(ix+1)$ and $\arg(ix)$ are asymptotically equal for large positive $x$.